# Cordova: adb: Command failed with exit code 255

Tags: android, cordova, build, phonegap-build

I get this output/error when

```
cordova run android --target 0152a65c02a27d5b --verbose
```

Output

```
    No scripts found for hook "before_run".
    No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
    Checking config.xml for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
    Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in android platform
    No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in android platform. Continuing...
    Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for android at /Users/r00/Projects/myappGo/myapp_app/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml
    Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific android config.xml
    Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/android/platform_www] to platforms/android/assets/www
    Wrote out android application name "myapp" to /Users/r00/Projects/myappGo/myapp_app/platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml
    Wrote out Android package name "com.myappgo.myapp" to /Users/r00/Projects/myappGo/myapp_app/platforms/android/src/com/myappgo/myapp/MainActivity.java
    This app does not have launcher icons defined
    This app does not have splash screens defined
    Prepared android project successfully
    No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
    Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
    ANDROID_HOME=/Users/r00/Library/Android/sdk
    JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
    Running command: /Users/r00/Projects/myappGo/myapp_app/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/r00/Projects/myappGo/myapp_app/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true

    BUILD SUCCESSFUL

    Total time: 1.695 secs
    Command finished with error code 0: /Users/r00/Projects/myappGo/myapp_app/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/r00/Projects/myappGo/myapp_app/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
    Built the following apk(s):
        /Users/r00/Projects/myappGo/myapp_app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
    No scripts found for hook "before_deploy".
    ANDROID_HOME=/Users/r00/Library/Android/sdk
    JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
    Running command: adb devices
    Command finished with error code 0: adb devices
    Running command: adb devices
    Command finished with error code 0: adb devices
    Running adb shell command "cat /proc/cpuinfo" on target 0152a65c02a27d5b...
    Running command: adb -s 0152a65c02a27d5b shell cat /proc/cpuinfo
    Command finished with error code 0: adb -s,0152a65c02a27d5b,shell,cat,/proc/cpuinfo
    Skipping build...
    Built the following apk(s):
        /Users/r00/Projects/myappGo/myapp_app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
    Using apk: /Users/r00/Projects/myappGo/myapp_app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
    Package name: com.myappgo.myapp
    Installing apk /Users/r00/Projects/myappGo/myapp_app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk on target 0152a65c02a27d5b...
    Running command: adb -s 0152a65c02a27d5b install -r /Users/r00/Projects/myappGo/myapp_app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
    Command finished with error code 255: adb -s,0152a65c02a27d5b,install,-r,/Users/r00/Projects/myappGo/myapp_app/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
    Error: adb: Command failed with exit code 255
        at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/r00/Projects/myappGo/myapp_app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
        at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
        at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:319:11)
        at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
        at Pipe._onclose (net.js:486:12)
```

I'm quiet lost here

Answer (score 1):

**My fix was to delete a few apps.**

The phone gave a hint; it kept popping-up a message that storage was low. However, I didn't think this was related to not being able to install the app (initially).

```
Connection: MTP (Media Device)
USB debugging: On
Device: LG Risio
Android version: 6.0
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Framework: Ionic 1.x
Ionic CLI: 2.2.1
Machine: Mac OS X Sierra
Node: 4.4.2
```

**Extra details:**

I kept switching between MTP and PTP connection. Restarted the device. And, I kept plugging and unplugging the device from my computer. Nothing worked. The build is always successful in the console. But somehow, the app just wasn't getting installed on the device. I deleted the old version of the app sometimes that can cause a problem where there are inconsistent versions. But that didn't work either. When I deleted 3 big apps from the phone and tried installing again `cordova run android`, the app was finally installed on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

From you command line run

```
adb -s 0152a65c02a27d5b shell cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

and check whether it fails and how.

As

```
Running command: adb devices
Command finished with error code 0: adb devices
```

may have succeeded perhaps you specific device is not detected or cannot obtain cpuinfo.